# Handling photo response from Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I can't figure out what actually is returned by this call and how I can display it in HTML as an `img` tag. When I use the same URI using the online Microsoft Graph Explorer test environment I get the image as intended.

```
var requestUri =
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/barfoo.onmicrosoft.com/users/xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx/photo/$value";

var request =
    new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri);

var accessToken =
    await _authenticationHelper.GetAccessTokenAsync();

request.Headers.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Answer (score 2):

`HttpClient` can give you the response as a `Stream`.

In ASP.NET Core, I've done this with:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProfilePhoto()
{
    //removed all the code which you already have
    HttpResponseMessage res = await client.SendAsync(request);

    return File(await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), "image/jpeg");
}
```

"Classic" ASP.NET MVC should be pretty identical, you would replace `IActionResult` with `ActionResult` at least.

You can then link this to an image tag like:

```
<img src="/Home/ProfilePhoto"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you have the users photo response you should be able to render the image along the following lines:
    src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ user.profilePic }}"

Comment: I think i have trouble before this. SendAsync(request) returns a HttpResponseMessage correct? How do i get a photo or blog from that?