# Convert photo from Microsoft Graph Client SDK to Base64String

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using an older implementation of an httpClient call to the Microsoft Graph to get a user's photo. The following code works but I'm using the Graph Client SDK now and things are done a little differently. I'm having a difficult time converting the code over as the samples and other references online don't seem to have the same methods.

## Old code:

```
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{webOptions.GraphApiUrl}/beta/me/photo/$value");
byte[] photo = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
return Convert.ToBase64String(photo);
```

## New code:

```
var graphServiceClient = await graphClient.GetAuthenticatedGraphClientAsync(HttpContext);
Stream photo = await graphServiceClient.Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

I've tried examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49108644/handling-photo-response-from-microsoft-graph) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461791/convert-image-to-base64string) but I'm a bit lost since `ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` is not available on the new `photo` object.

Comment: Take a look at the following post: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Graph/How-to-get-user-photo-in-C-using-Graph-API/td-p/94781  -- the OP in the post, provides the answer to his own question, and I believe you will find the code in that answer for the use case you are looking for.  The answer has an extension method that makes a call to GraphAPI to get an image via `ReadAsStreamAsync()` but returns a `Task<byte[]>` to callers.

Comment: Thanks but that is the same method I was using. The return object is different in the new method. It is a ‘stream’ type.

Comment: The OPs question use the same method but the _answer is different_ and deals directly with `stream` -- look closely at the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `msgraph-sdk-dotnet` for [`Get photo` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) supports to return photo content as a [`Stream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=netframework-4.8) only

```
public interface IProfilePhotoContentRequest : IBaseRequest
{
    /// <summary>Gets the stream.</summary>
    /// <returns>The stream.</returns>
    Task<Stream> GetAsync();

    /// <summary>Gets the stream.</summary>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The <see cref="T:System.Threading.CancellationToken" /> for the request.</param>
    /// <param name="completionOption">The <see cref="T:System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption" /> to pass to the <see cref="T:Microsoft.Graph.IHttpProvider" /> on send.</param>
    /// <returns>The stream.</returns>
    Task<Stream> GetAsync(
      CancellationToken cancellationToken,
      HttpCompletionOption completionOption = HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);

    //...
}
```

and [`Convert.ToBase64String` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netframework-4.8) accepts a byte array, the following example demonstrates how to convert the original example:

```
var graphServiceClient = await graphClient.GetAuthenticatedGraphClientAsync(HttpContext);
var photoStream = await graphServiceClient.Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
var photoBytes = ReadAsBytes(photoStream);
var result = Convert.ToBase64String(photoBytes);
```

where

```
//Convert Stream to bytes array  
public static byte[] ReadAsBytes(Stream input)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        input.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```